# Jasmine - why does it give me an error on a simple getElementsByTagName(...)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tdd, jasmine

Html:

```
<ul id="listONE">
      <li class="{{isSel}}" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="selPersonToChange(this)">{{person.nome +" - "+ person.citta}}</li>
</ul>
```

Piece of my script.js with AngularJS (1.3.1):

```
mymod.controller("maincontroller", function($scope){

    $scope.people = [
        { name: "name1", city: "city1" },
        { name: "name2", city: "city2" },
        { name: "name3", city: "city3" }
    ];

    $scope.oldIndex = 0;
    $scope.oldPerson = 0;
$scope.selPersonToChange = function(){

    $scope.personToChange.person = this.person;
    $scope.personToChange.index = this.$index;

    lis = document.getElementById("listONE").getElementsByTagName("li");//here it report an error
    for(i=0; i<lis.length; i++){ lis[i].className = ""; }
    lis[this.$index].className = "selected";
    return true;        
}
```

Jasmine tdd:

```
Jasmine tdd.js:

describe("myApp", function(){

    beforeEach(module("mymod"));

    describe("maincontroller", function(){

        var scope;
        var ctrl;
        var els;
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $compile){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller("maincontroller", {$scope:scope});
            els = $compile('<ul id="listONE"><li class="{{isSel}}" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="selPersonToChange(this)">{{person.nome +" - "+ person.citta}}</li></ul>')(scope);
            scope.$digest();   
            console.log(els.html());

        }));

        it("Is ul #listONE null or undefined?", function(){
            expect(scope.selPersonToChange()).toEqual(true);
        }); 


    });

});
```

The real problem is "document.getElementById('listONE')", because it return to me that "listONE" doesn't exist.

Comment: Is it `null` or `undefined`, there's a difference? If it's `null`, the element doesn't exists at the time you're calling `getElementById`

Comment: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for your controller to find that element because in your test you're not telling AngularJS to "load" any view. You're just instantiating the controller which doesn't load your html.

If you're using ngRoute module in your app, you could try to inject and use in your test the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) service in order to force a path to be loaded, which involves using the controller and loading the assigned template. Let's say that you have `/some/path` path that uses your controller and your html. You could do a `$location.path('/some/path')` and a `$rootScope.$apply()` before your assertions.

If you're not using ngRoute, I guess that you could try to [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) a template defined in your tests that includes some `<div ng-controller="maincontroller">...</div>` code in it.

Comment: Sorry, but I've copied just a piece of html.. I've used ng-controller, obvioulsy.

Comment: Ok, but my point stands: you either need to use $location to force a path change in your test or $compile the template in your tests before making the assertions. You can find an example of what I'm talking about (first approach) here: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/

Comment: So should I write/add:

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $location){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller("maincontroller", {$scope:scope});
            $location.path("index.html");
}));

given that tdd.js is into the same dir of index.html.

Comment: That's what I think, but only if you're using ngRoute module in your app.

Comment: I'm not using ngRoute in my app

Comment: Ok, then you should use `$compile` service to let angular compile a piece of html for you and have it bound to your controller. Check out this really good video showing how to do it for testing a directive, which is more or less the same as what you're trying to do: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-unit-testing-a-directive

Comment: I've tried, nothign to do, the same error.
Take a look at the new one code, that I've modified.

Comment: The real problem is "document.getElementById('listONE')", because it return to me that "listONE" doesn't exist.